# Doorkeeper with MongoId

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the Doorkeeper gem to work with Mongoid.
According to their github page (https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) I just need to add the following to the configuration file
but when I do that I get the error: undefined method `orm'.

Am I doing it right? Do I need to do anything else but adding this line?

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :mongoid
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using MongoID 3 and this gem currenly only supports 2.4. Works fine now.

Comment: This is only working with doorkeeper 0.5. Until it is released, use it from git as described in this issue: https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/issues/98

Comment: Mongoid 3 is available on `master` branch now :-)